# Store Python function in JSON

Tags: python, json, user-defined-functions

Say I have a JSON file as such:

```
{
  "x":5,
  "y":4,
  "func" : def multiplier(a,b):
               return a*d
}
```

This over-simplifies what I want to try and do, but basically I am attempting
to story a python UDF into a JSON file. Is there a way to do this so that when I 
do:

```
with open('config.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

I can access those values and do something like:

```
v1, v2 = data['x'], data['y']
mult = data['func']
print(mult(v1,v2))
```

To get expected output: 20
**NOTE**: To my understanding JSON doesn't store functions, so maybe I can store it as a string, and then in my python script parse the string into a function? Not too sure.

Comment: That's *not* a JSON file. It's also not valid Python dictionary syntax.

Comment: How do you feel about writing the function in a .py file instead, and importing that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe minus the function definition, everything else seems fine about my JSON file. I'm trying to ask a way to work around this which is why I suggested wrapping the function definition in quotes to try and parse it using python into a valid function.

Comment: @Kevin that would work...but I'm trying to see if there is a way to store that module in the JSON (maybe store the module name as a string and import it that way?

Comment: I would suggest you to go with XML if you are thinking of storing this in a file format that is not executable by python and can be accessed in any language of your choice.

Comment: Sure, storing just the module and function name in the json is technically feasible... [`import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) can import a module given its name, and you can get a function given its name using `getattr`. But it's hard to say whether this is the most practical approach for whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve by storing the function definition in JSON?

Comment: @MatsLindh basically I have a main script that users can pass a config (dictionary) into. Right now the config is a .py, but I'm considering moving it to a JSON format. So I can store all my other data in the JSON fine, except the only thing I am having real trouble wrapping my head around is letting the user pass a user defined function into the JSON. One option is to pass the name of a .py module (which the user also must write that contains their UDFs), and then the main script would get those functions from the modules passed through the config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need to store a function in an external JSON file, one solution could be to store a lambda function as a value and use the `eval` function to evaluate it from your script.

But be aware that using `eval` in your code could be dangerous, please consider the security implications before using it (see [this](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#minimizing-the-security-issues-of-eval) article from realpython.com).

**config.json**

```
{
  "x": 5,
  "y": 4,
  "function": "lambda x, y : x * y"
}
```

**Your Python file (test.py)**

```
import json


def run():
    """Run function from JSON config."""

    with open("config.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    x, y = data["x"], data["y"]
    multiplier = eval(data["function"])
    return multiplier(x, y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   result = run()
   print(result)
```

**Demo**

```
In[2]: ls
test.py
config.json

In[3]: import json

In[4]: def run():
  ...:     """Run function from JSON config."""
  ...: 
  ...:     with open("config.json") as f:
  ...:         data = json.load(f)
  ...: 
  ...:     x, y = data["x"], data["y"]
  ...:     multiplier = eval(data["func"])
  ...:     return(multiplier(x, y))
  ...:    

In[5]: run()
20
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! lambas are a great option, something that I need to get super used to writing as they can cut down the wordiness of UDFs. I will also be testing this method to see how complex I can get with my solution. Thank you again!

Comment: Be careful using `eval`.  There are no checks and thus easily exploited.

Answer (score 12):

Python has a built in module name `marshal` that can handle this.

```
import marshal, ujson as json

def multiplier(a, b):
    return a * b

x = {
  "x":5,
  "y":4,
  "func" : marshal.dumps(multiplier.func_code)
}

x = json.dumps(x)
print(x)
```

And to get it back...

```
x = json.loads(x)
x = marshal.loads(x['func'])
# maybe save the function name in dict
func = types.FunctionType(x, globals(), "some_func_name") 

print(func(2,4))
```

Comment: hmm marshal looks helpful. It seems like an extra step to dumps first and then get it back, especially considering that I want to start from a JSON not from a python script, but I will see if I can implement this also. Thank you!

Comment: I included JSON because that was the format you wanted?  How do you propose converting the marshal easily without converting into a python object?

Answer (score 2):

Something that is worth trying is just saving it as a string.

You can do stuff like

```
my_func = "
def function(a,b):
   constant = {input_var}
   return a*b + constant
"
my_func.format(input_var = 5)

exec(my_func)
function(1,2) # will return 7
```

This will create object of the function that you can call. Not really sure what you are trying to do but creating a json file like below should give you what you want to do:
(I added the 'func' wrapper because I am assuming you will have multiple functions in one JSON)

```
function_json = {
'func': {
    'x':5
    'y':4
    'multiplier':
'def multiplier(a,b):
    return a*b'
}

x=function_json['func']['x']
y=function_json['func']['y']
exec(function_json['func']['multiplier'])
multiplier(x,y) # will return 20
```

hope this helps

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! I was unaware of 'exec' but I tried it and it works. I'll have to do some testing to see how complex I can get with this method

Comment: I'd be careful with eval... it can be very dangerous...  but I guess so could this.

Comment: Exec and eval do have issues, however the benefit of exec() over eval() is that it can take a whole block of code like a function and execute that. I find that exec() would work better than eval() for this application.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried out and combined solutions from [ethan-kulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10067479/ethan-kulla) and [eatmeimadanish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591014/eatmeimadanish)

The following code works:

```
my_func = '''
def function(a,b):
   constant = {input_var}
   return a*b + constant
'''

exec(my_func.format(input_var=5), globals())
# For Python 3.x, use globals() to change global context
function(2,2)
```