# Python return function to JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, object

I am beginner to working with JSON, and now i'm gonna play it with Python.
Recently i have make code like this:

```
import json


def product():
    itemId = 84576454
    itemName = 'FGX Flannel Shirt'
    price = 195000
    availableColorAndSize = {
        'color': {'blue-black': ['M', 'L', 'XL'],
                  'black-white': ['L']}
    }

    freeShiping = False
```

The output file should look something like this:

```
{"Stuff":{
    "id":84576454,
    "name":"Shoes",
    "cost":431200,
    "color_and_size": {
        "color": {
            "brown":["XL", "XXL", "M"],
            "green":["XXL"]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Before i have follow this one: [Store Python function in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936785/store-python-function-in-json)
But i'm still confused and not sure how to return that function to make a JSON.

Comment: What exactly do you mean *"return a JSON file"*? Have you done some research around the functionality Python has for dealing with JSON?

Comment: @jonrsharpe return a value in JSON format

Comment: So do you mean as a string?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, right..
sorry but i have try research this code before
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936785/store-python-function-in-json

Comment: Spend some time skimming the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). You never know [what](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) you might find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Python's built-in JSON library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) can do this for you. The four main functions are as follows:

> json.load() loads a JSON formatted **file** and returns a Python dictionary >object.
>
> json.loads() returns a Python dictionary object from a JSON formatted
> **string**.
>
> json.dump() returns a JSON formatted **file** from a Python dictionary
> object
>
> json.dumps() returns a JSON formatted **string** from a Python
> dictionary object

So you could use:

```
import json


def product():
    itemId = 12341822
    itemName = 'FGX Flannel Shirt'
    price = 195000
    availableColorAndSize = {
        'color': {'blue-black': ['M', 'L', 'XL'],
                  'black-white': ['L']}
    }

    freeShiping = False
    
    # Returns a JSON formatted file based on the dictionary shown
    return json.dump(
        {'itemId': itemId,
         'itemName': itemName,
         'price': price,
         'availableColorAndSize': availableColorAndSize,
         'freeShiping': freeShiping})
```

Comment: Thank you so much @wiomoc, its work perfectly.