# pickle.dump(stats, items, outfile) TypeError: an integer is required (got type _io.BufferedWriter)

Tags: python, python-3.8

```
#!Python 3.8.3
#Dungeon Game Similar to dungeons and dragons, turn fight game

import pickle, time, sys, random
filename = "Save_File"

load = input("Would you like to load a save? y/n")
if load == "y":
    try:
        infile = open(filename, "rb")
        pickle.load(infile)
        infile.close()
    except:
        print("It seems you typed your save name wrong. Resart the program to try again")
        pass
        
NameInput = input("Enter Your Characters Name Here To Start Your Journey:")
ClassType = input("What Class Do You Choose? Mage, Healer, Barbarian, Archer, Warrior?")


stats = {
    "Health" : "100",
    "Gold" : "50",
    "Name" : NameInput,
    "ClassType" : ClassType,
    "melee" : "10",
    "defence" : "0"
    }
items = {
    "Healing Potion" : "0",
    "Amber" : "0",
    "Amethyst" : "0",
    "Arrows" : "0",
    "Azurite" : "0",
    "Backpack" : "0"
    }

outfile = open(filename, "wb")
pickle.dump(stats, items, outfile)
outfile.close()
```

So i have this problem anyone know how to fix it? The error is in the title. I making a game that will be a turn based game and i am going to use a save feature to save your progress. It can someone plaese explain this error and how to fix it please.

Comment: By the way i'm only saving right now to check if the save feature works

Comment: Could you show us what your exact error is?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in another question.
[Store Python function in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936785/store-python-function-in-json/51938459#51938459)

Python has a built in module name `marshal` that can handle this.

```
import marshal, ujson as json

def multiplier(a, b):
    return a * b

x = {
  "x":5,
  "y":4,
  "func" : marshal.dumps(multiplier.func_code)
}

x = json.dumps(x)
print(x)
```

And to get it back...

```
x = json.loads(x)
x = marshal.loads(x['func'])
# maybe save the function name in dict
func = types.FunctionType(x, globals(), "some_func_name") 

print(func(2,4))
```